# All checkboxes getting checked even if one is checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I'm making a basic todo app in angularjs. 
Here's the code that's used to create a new todo with a checkbox

```
<div class="container" ng-controller = 'controller' >

    <h3>Enter Todo </h3> <input type="text" ng-model = 'new'>
    <button ng-click = 'add();' ng-disabled="status();">Add</button>

    <div ng-repeat = "i in todo" >
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model = "todo.done" /> <label>{{i.name}}</label>
     </div>

</div>
```

The problem is that all the checkboxes get checked even when I check just one

Here's my controller module

```
todoApp.controller('controller',['$scope',function($scope){ 
 $scope.new = '';   
 $scope.todo = [];

 $scope.add = function(){
    $scope.todo.push({name : $scope.new, done: false});
    console.log($scope.todo);
    $scope.new = '';
 };

 $scope.status = function(){
    return !(/\S+/.test($scope.new));
 };
```

Comment: your code isn't complete. please include all the necessary code to make a working version of your code (given that the error was fixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ng-model = "i.done"
```

should solve the problem. In your version `ng-model = "todo.done"` **todo** is an array and angular just creates a property on the fly, when it's used for the first time. This way all of your checkboxes are connected to this property, that's why checking one checkbox affects all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Because the list of the checkbox are sharing the same model. You can create a custom directive or you can use checklist-model directive.

Demo URL:
https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/